# Multiple search between two tables

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have two tables - the first (this is just an example but the original query is a pretty big)

| item_id_t1 | serial_num_t1 | country_t1 | customer | snapshot_date_t1 | serial_num_trunc_t1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 156648107 | 222-99950578 | AAA | BBSS | 12/1/2022 | 99950578 |
| 156648107 | 222-99950578 | AAA | BBSS | 11/1/2022 | 99950578 |
| 156648107 | 222-99950578 | AAA | BBSS | 1/1/2023 | 99950578 |
| 108279887 | 888-515179765 | AAA | BBSS | 12/1/2022 | 515179765 |
| 108279887 | 888-515179765 | AAA | BBSS | 11/1/2022 | 515179765 |
| 108279887 | 888-515179765 | AAA | BBSS | 11/1/2023 | 515179765 |

and the second one

| serial_num_trunc_t2 | serial_num_t2 | up_ind_t2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99950578 | 333-99950578 | 1 |
| 515179765 | 888-515179765 | 1 |

Now, my first step would be to find a match based on serial_num_t1 = serial_num_t2 and the second part of the code should be to find all unmatched records but this time based on serial_num_trunc_t1 = serial_num_trunc_t2.

I started with CTE tables first

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT * FROM t1),
t2 AS (SELECT * FROM t2)

SELECT a.*
(SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON serial_num_t1 = serial_num_t2) a

INNER JOIN

(SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.serial_num_trunc_t1 = t2.serial_num_trunc_t1
WHERE q.up_ind_t2 <> 1) b
ON a.serial_num_trunc_t1 = b.serial_num_trunc_t2
```

and here I am stuck. How to compare unmatched values from table "a" again with table "b" based ON t1.serial_num_trunc_t1 = t2.serial_num_trunc_t2 WHERE t2.ip_ind_t2 <> 1
My final table should have six records (like t1) and "up_ind_t2" should be filled with 1 for all six records in the final table.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this is what I needed.

```
with 
ib as (
select * 
from [dbo].[ib] i
left join [dbo].[qu] q
on i.serial_num_t1=q.serial_num_t2),

qu as (
select * 
from [dbo].[ib] i
right join [dbo].[qu] q
on i.serial_num_trunc_t1=q.serial_num_trunc_t2)

select ff.*
from
(select * 
from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY q.item_id_t1,
q.serial_num_t1,q.country_t1, q.customer, q.snapshot_date_t1,
q.up_ind_t2 ORDER BY q.snapshot_date_t1, q.up_ind_t2 DESC) AS it_row, q.* 
from qu q
left join ib b
on q.serial_num_trunc_t2 = b.serial_num_trunc_t1) a 

union

select 99 as it_row, zz.* 
from qu as zz ) ff
where it_row = 1
```

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, you want

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT * FROM t1),
t2 AS (SELECT * FROM t2)

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON serial_num_t1 = serial_num_t2

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.serial_num_trunc_t1 = t2.serial_num_trunc_t1
WHERE q.up_ind_t2 <> 1
```

as Query,the LEft JOIN doesn't make that much sense in the firstplace, so i removed ot from the second.

the second query implies that you have only 1 record for every serial_num_trunc_t2 and that is not equal to 1, if not you need to add limit

Answer (score 0):

@nbk
It doesn't look like my solution. I added match_level in order to see from where a match comes: from LEFT JOIN or from INNER JOIN (UNION part of the code).
So, when I run your code I get the same results as before UNION ALL part

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT * FROM ib),
t2 AS (SELECT * FROM qu)

SELECT t1.*, t2.*, 1 as match_level
FROM ib t1
LEFT JOIN qu t2
ON serial_num_t1 = serial_num_t2

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.*, t2.*, 2 as match_level
FROM ib t1
INNER JOIN qu t2
ON t1.serial_num_trunc_t1 = t2.serial_num_trunc_t2
WHERE t2.up_ind_t2 <> 1
```

[image: Code results]

Comment: that looks exactly like my query, with out the new labels

Comment: But your query doesn't return me desired results. In final table all fields serial_num_trunc_t2, serial_num_t2 and up_ind_t2 should be filed (based on UNION part) and it is not a case in this situation.

Comment: Is there some better solution, maybe, for this? First step is LEFT JOIN t1 on t1 based on serial_num. And it will find three match records for serial_num = 888-51517965.
Next, I need additional search between t1 and t2 tables for all unmatched records from first query where up_ind_t2 is NULL based on serial_num_trunc_t1 = serial_num_trunc_t2 and then to merge/combine these records into one table.

Comment: I think I found a solution but need to test it on the whole set of the data.
I changed:
- UNION ALL ---> UNION 
- WHERE t2.up_ind_t2 <> 1 ---> WHERE t2.up_ind_t2 IS NULL

Comment: the NULL come from the LEFT JOIN without it you wouldn't have any,